# changing numpy array values from zero to -1

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a numpy array consisting of ones and zeros which are randomly arranged.

```
numpy.array([[0,1,1],[1,0,0]])
```

How can I change zeros to -1 without changing the ones?

Comment: `a[a==0] = -1`? Reading up on `masking` might help.

Comment: Or `a = 2*a - 1`.

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed out in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42875900/changing-numpy-array-values-from-zero-to-1/42876293#comment72855917_42875900) there are basically two ways to replace the values. Either using [boolean array indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing) to change the values in-place:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.array([[0,1,1],[1,0,0]])
>>> arr[arr==0] = -1
>>> arr 
array([[-1,  1,  1],
       [ 1, -1, -1]])
```

You might want to check the intermediate steps for the `arr == 0` (creating a mask) and `arr[arr == 0]` (getting only the values of the array where the mask is True, in this case where the value is 0) to understand what is going on.

Or if you want to create a copy of the array with the values replaced there is [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
>>> np.where(arr==0, -1, arr)
array([[-1,  1,  1],
       [ 1, -1, -1]])
```

This creates a new array and uses the second argument wherever the condition (first argument) is True and otherwise uses the second arguments items.